# Google account login broke on old tablet/android

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-account, samsung-galaxy-tab-8.9

I have an old Galaxy Tab 8.9 (GT-P7300) tablet with Android 4.0.4 (Samsung original firmware update, not rooted). It mostly sits in the drawer and sees very infrequent use.

Today I booted it up and everything related to Google account on it is locked up (including Play Market), giving following error:

> Google
>
> 404. That's an error.
>
> The requested URL /o/oauth/GetOAuthToken was not found on this server. That's all we know.

If I click on Google logo I get dumped to the regular Google web search page, where I can login fine but which doesn't resolve the issue.

Had Google just abandoned older Android versions or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to accounts in settings and tried to force sync on Google account. It threw the same error multiple times, but must have shaken the issue out somehow — login suddenly worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the account and adding it again solved the problem for me.